# MongoDB insertion based on reading

Tags: mongodb, insert

In my data, I need to look up if a combination of attributes exist in database yet. If so I just update it, if not I will insert a new doc. I know it is easy in relational database if we set a combination of attributes as primary key, but I don't find the same thing in Mongo. Now I simply set this combination as index, query the database to find if count is zero, then decide to update or insert. However with the growth of data size (currently 2Mill docs), the query ate up memory much faster than inserting without query. Does anyone have good idea?

Comment: have you tried [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag)?

Comment: I thought about it before. The reason I didn't use it was that I only need to update a few attributes, not all. Is it more efficient to use upsert and always update all fields?

Comment: You could use [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) operator, it's more efficient than update all fields

Comment: Can you explain that? Because if I insert docs, I need all attributes (including the key combination and other attributes). If I just update docs, I just need to update a small proportion of other attributes.

Comment: I tried my methods just now, no significant difference.. I guess it's because whatever update requires reading

Comment: Finally I inserted one file's in a temp collection to narrow down the query range. Then when all data in that file have been read, I insert the whole collection into the large collection and drop the temp one. So all indexes dropped and memory didn't go up. :)